# Selecting small motor (wrist watch sized)

Tags: motor, actuator

I want to build a skydiving altimeter, which is a device with a pointer that looks like and is slightly bigger than a wrist watch. In this device I want to display altitude information using a pointer, again, in clock-like fashion.

It needs to have continuous and bi-directional rotation motion, so I'm initially discarding analog meters.

What type of motor fits the bill?

Comment: "Pager" vibrator motors may be small enough for you. Look on Digikey for motors. I think that may be yhe only type they have.

Comment: @Russell - vibration motors have an very short life, and while small in diameter, are often rather long (> 10 mm)

Comment: @stevenh - Needs must :-). The key dimension is, arguably, the smallest one. A right angle drive reduces height to what minimum dimension will fit inside. Hub drive and great ingenuity then reduces width to slightly more than max dimension. I suspect that a pager motor lifetime would suffice for his app. Maybe not. TBD. Or you go more conventional with eg [this 24mm dia by ~= 12mm deep one](http://www.nmbtc.com/pdf/motors/MDN3.pdf). Example only

Comment: What do they use to actuate the pointers of wrist watches?

Comment: @Russel - I like the idea. I already have one of those in my design (for vibration actually). The only problem I saw so far is that these motors spin too fast. I don't know if I can cram in the necessary reduction to achieve the target RPM (around 1/60 RPM) with great precision.

Comment: @PaduMerloti - Do you need around 1/60 RPM, or precisely 1/60 RPM?  This will determine whether you should look for a stepper-type motor, or a normal DC motor with an encoder and a huge step-down gearbox.

Comment: The smallest motors I've ever seen were Piezoelectric Motors.  (Just my $0.02).

Comment: @Kevin - Around 1/60 RPM. The application is an skydiving altimeter, so motion is continuous

Comment: @NickAlexeev - it's your $0.02, but it's his $8000 for the piezo motor.

Comment: I've been looking at lavet type stepping motors, the ones used inside wrist watches. With some smart gears, it should fit perfectly in my application. The problem I'm having is finding a source to buy it and to find one that is bidirectional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digikey have (despite my prior suggestion au contraire) a large number of motors.

As an example only something like this MAY fit inside your spec - [24mm dia x about 12mm deep](http://www.nmbtc.com/pdf/motors/MDN2.pdf). Some what large as a "wristwatch".

Or you could lay this down with a right angle drive and hub drive of he "hand(s)".
 [About 16mm long and about 5mm across](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NMB-MAT/KHN4NX1RC.pdf) so you could fit inside an eg 20mm x 7 or so mm "watch" with suitable magic.

**BUT**

You could almost certainly build your own motor with less effort than you might expect.
 A stepper motor type arrangement with a multi tooth disk and only two windings will allow unidirectional drive. Three windings and a toothed disk will allow you to make a basic stepper motor. You can add zero current hold in place with a permanent magnet if desired.

---

As Olin notes - it would be easier to implement something that LOOKED like what you have described but used a "sold state" display of some sort. Doing it mechanically is liable to be worthwhile only if you value the result for its artistic merits.

Answer (score 3):

Since size, weight, and power are all important issues, I would seriously look into not using mechanical motion.  See if you can find a LCD or maybe OLED graphics display.  Then you draw something moving as you want, but it doesn't have to physically move.  The rest is ASMOF (a small matter of firmware).

Comment: The design does incorporate an OLED display, but this design also calls for a mechanical pointer spinning around.

Answer (score 2):

I like Russell's suggestion of making your own motor. It's not actually as hard as you might think if you've need zero torque. Take a look at the motors used in wrist watches. I couldn't remember the name until someone mentioned them. They're called Lavet style motors and are a single pole stepper motor. It can only go in one direction, and turns 90º at a time.

[image: Lavet motor]

However, you could easily add another pole and winding, so that you can make it turn 90º at a time, and be able to rotate both ways.

By microstepping (controlling the current in the two windings to be a sin and cosin wave) you can do much less than 90º movements.

[image: Microstepping]

Take a look at stepper motor driver chips which incorporate microstepping like the Allegro [A4982](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A4982-Datasheet.ashx). You simply ask them to take 1 step in either direction, and they sort out the current in the two windings.